# Is there an easy way to reorder items in a ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView data bound to an ObservableCollection. I set the CanReorderItems property to true.

However, when I drag items in the listview, they stay in their original position.

Is there any easy way to enable reordering in a list view?

Here is my code:
ctor of page:

```
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> c = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    c.Add(new MyClass("a"));
    c.Add(new MyClass("b"));
    c.Add(new MyClass("c"));
    DataContext = c;
}
```

XAML of page:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanDragItems="true" CanReorderItems="true" AllowDrop="True"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d7a81b1b-c87b-4976-966c-38562315d9df) in ListView and GridView now (note the question was asked before Windows 8.0 released) and you need to use a CollectionViewSource:

```
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> c = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    c.Add(new MyClass("a"));
    c.Add(new MyClass("b"));
    c.Add(new MyClass("c"));
    var viewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = c };

    DataContext = viewSource.View;
}
```

Comment: Filip, thank you for your reply. It does not reorder the items though. Is there anything else I should be doing? (listen to an event?)

Comment: What do you have in your items? If you have buttons - they might not work, but you can replace them with a custom button implementation like the ListItemButton - http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/13059#246007

Comment: I don't have custom items, see sample above.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right - seems like you can drag items around and there are indicators that you can drop them in a new location, but they don't stay in place... Maybe it does not work with ItemsSource or you would need to handle some events to rearrange the ItemsSource collection... Did you ask in the MSDN forums yet? There's usually someone from MSFT there who can help with such problems.

Comment: Right there: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d7a81b1b-c87b-4976-966c-38562315d9df - it seems like there is a bug in ListView/GridView and you need to use CollectionViewSource as a sort of proxy to your ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on AllowDrop and have your ItemsSource be an ObservableCollection or ICollectionViewSource.